# I doing a course of React and i have a error when i try add a functionality to my course project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is the error**

*Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `PhotoCardWithQuery`.*

**This is my code**

`PhotoCardWithQuery.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { PhotoCard } from '../components/PhotoCard'
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'
import { Query } from '@apollo/client'

const GET_SINGLE_PHOTO = gql`
query getSinglePhoto($id:ID!) {
  photo(id:$id) {
    id
    categoryId
    src
    likes
    userId
    liked
  }
}
`

const renderProp = ({ loading, error, data }) => {
  if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>

  const { photo = {} } = data
  return <PhotoCard {...photo} />
}

export const PhotoCardWithQuery = ({ id }) => (
  <Query query={GET_SINGLE_PHOTO} variables={{ id }}>
    {renderProp}
  </Query>
)
```

`Detail.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { PhotoCardWithQuery } from '../container/PhotoCardWithQuery'

export const Detail = ({ detailId }) => (
  <PhotoCardWithQuery id={detailId} />
)
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { GlobalStyle } from './styles/GlobalStyles'
import { Logo } from './components/Logo'
import { Home } from './pages/Home'
import { Router } from '@reach/router'
import { Detail } from './pages/Detail'

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Logo />
      <Router>
        <Home path='/' />
        <Home path='/pet/:id' />
        <Detail path='/detail/:detailId' />
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`PhotoCard.js`

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Article, ImgWrapper, Img } from './styles'
import { useLocalStorage } from '../../hooks/useLocalStorage'
import { useNearScreen } from '../../hooks/useNearScreen'
import { FavButton } from '../FavButton/index.js'
import { ToggleLikeMutation } from '../../container/ToggleLikeMutation'
import { Link } from '@reach/router'

const DEFAULT_IMAGE = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60'

export const PhotoCard = ({
  id, likes = 0,
  src = DEFAULT_IMAGE
}) => {
  const [show, element] = useNearScreen()
  const key = `like-${id}`
  const [liked, setLiked] = useLocalStorage(key, false)

  return (
    <Article ref={element}>
      {
        show &&
          <>
            <Link to={`/detail/${id}`}>
              <ImgWrapper>
                <Img src={src} />
              </ImgWrapper>
            </Link>

            <ToggleLikeMutation>
              {
                (toggleLike) => {
                  const handleFavClick = () => {
                    !liked && toggleLike({
                      variables: {
                        input: { id }
                      }
                    })

                    setLiked(!liked)
                  }

                  return (
                    <FavButton
                      liked={liked} likes={likes} onClick={handleFavClick}
                    />
                  )
                }
              }
            </ToggleLikeMutation>
          </>
      }
    </Article>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you show also `PhotoCard` and how it's exported? Also, you forgot to invoke `renderProp` and pass an argument object to it, i.e. `{renderProp({ loading: ...., error: ....., data: .....})}`.

Comment: Actually, I think the child function is ok and excepted syntax. I think the issue is with `PhotoCard`.

Comment: @DrewReese  yes i can, i edited the post with the `PhotoCard`.

Comment: Ok, `PhotoCard` is exported and imported as a named export/import. What version of `Apollo` are you using? The `Query` Component and API is deprecated (though I don't think removed). Do you have any stacktrace available with the error that you could post up in your question?

Comment: @Drew Reese i use the version `3.3.12` in Apollo and no,  i don't have an stacktrace ¿can you sendme a link or something to learn how to generate that? thank you!